# VLC tagging limitations?

Tags: vlc-media-player, tags

I've been looking for a media library/player and thought VLC was a candidate, but I'm not seeing the variety of tags I need to organize my music, looks like only track title, artist (at track level), album name, genre, and a couple others that don't have much value to me.  I would like to see album artist distinct from track artist, and also sub-genre, like latin/cumbia or Africa/soukous.  Am using 2.1.1 with XP machine.  Am I missing something or should I be looking at a different media organizer?